# CSS: How to show my current location on the map?

Tags: css

I want to add to my site my current location on the map for example like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpxu6.jpg)

I tried to copy from the site but I can't do the CSS part:

```
<div class="info-map">Israel,<br>Ramat Gan,<br>Ha-agada 9, 5237749 <br><br><span>shoniki951@gmail.com</span></div>
<div class="map-wrap">
  <div
    class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom"
    tabindex="0" style="outline: none;">
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(22px, -146px, 0px);">
      <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
        <div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;">
          <div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated"
            style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(160px, 4px, 0px) scale(1);"><img alt=""
              src="https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4888/3324.png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(250px, 167px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
              alt="" src="https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4887/3324.png"
              class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-6px, 167px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt=""
              src="https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4887/3325.png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-6px, 423px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt=""
              src="https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4886/3324.png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-262px, 167px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
              alt="" src="https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4886/3325.png"
              class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-262px, 423px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
              alt="" src="https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4888/3325.png"
              class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(250px, 423px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
              alt="" src="https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4887/3323.png"
              class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-6px, -89px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt=""
              src="https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/13/4888/3323.png" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
              style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(250px, -89px,
```

Comment: could you provide more info please

Comment: I want to add to my website a map like this according to the picture according to my place of residence